# Backbone Model and firing off to a different endpoint on attribute click event

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I have a backbone model that fetches the data from the server,

```
var Post = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url:"api/post"
});
```

on fetch it returns and populates the model like below

```
{
  by: 1,
  vote: 1,
  text: "I am a post"
}
```

and I have a list view that renders these items into following html

```
<span className='vote'>
   <i className='up-vote'></i>
       1
   <i className='down-vote'></i>
</span>
```

What I want to do is when user clicks on the upvote icon I want to fire  a **PUT** request to the  server whose endpoint looks like

```
"api/post/:id/vote"
```

What I am struggling with is, because the vote attribute is part of the Post model how do I fire off to this different endpoint using the existing Post model, as I have the vote attribute as a part of the Post model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two options:

- One would be to override [Backbone.sync](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#Sync).
- The other option is to use an AJAX request, which I think it's way simpler.

The code of your view for the second option would be something like this:

```
events : {
    'click #up-vote' : 'sendPutRequest', 
},
sendPutRequest: function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/post/' + this.model.get('id') + '/vote',
        type: 'PUT',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(this.model.toJSON()),
        success: function(result) {
            // Do something with the result
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I was kind of looking into a more backbone way of doing the same stuff. Create a new model for the vote attribute and have it's own url attribute but struggled how all that would work in conjunction with each other. Probably overriding Backbone.sync is the way to go.

Comment: Well, you asked how do it with your current schema. But for sure, the best option would be to have a **PostModel** with an attribute that it's a **VotesCollection** whose elements are **VoteModel**...

Comment: Ended up doing something similar to the answer as overwriting backbone sync did not quite fit what I wanted in the end.